# Enhanced for loop error

Tags: java, for-loop

[image]

```
public class ArrayMethodsTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int[] tester = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
        ArrayMethods test = new ArrayMethods(tester);
        for(int element : test)
        {
            System.out.print(element + " ");
        }
        test.shiftRight();
        for(int element : test) //error: for-each not applicable to expression type
        {
            System.out.print(element + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

I figure what the problem is. Thanks to jigar joshi. However I still need to use the ArrayMethods methods for the tester that I created. I know that they work but how can it be possible to provide a tester class for an object that isn't an array since the methods are for arrays.

```
public class ArrayMethods
{
    public int[] values;
    public ArrayMethods(int[] initialValues)
    {
        values = initialValues;
    }
    public void swapFirstAndLast()
    {
        int first = values[0];
        values[0] = values[values.length-1];
        values[values.length-1] = first;

    }
    public void shiftRight()
    {
        int first = 0;
        int second = first;
       for(int i =0; i < values.length; i++) 
       {
        if(i < values.length-1)
        {
            first = values[i];
            second = values[i+1];
            values[i+ 1] = first;
        }
        if(i == values.length)
        {
            values[i] = values[0];
        }
       }
    }

}
//0,1,2,3,4,5
//5,0,1,2,3,4
```

Comment: You're clearly referencing a non-`Iterable` in your for-each loop.

Comment: What is the code for ArrayMethods? Does the code also error on the first `for(int element : test)`?

Comment: Since the array in your `ArrayMethods` class is public you can use `for(int element : test.values)`

Comment: ohhh, now I know. thanks

Answer (score 1):

`test` is reference of `ArrayMethods` which is not an `Iterable` or an array type and so is the error

Answer (score 0):

You've already encountered the issue in which you can't iterate over an `ArrayMethods`, since it's not iterable.  What it seems like you want to *do* is iterate over its values instead, considering that `values` is a public field.

```
for(int element : test.values) {
    System.out.print(element + " ");
}
```